# React array inside state doesn't change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```js
scriptWriter = (data:ItemType) => {
    let id = data.id
    console.log(this.state.items.map(el => el.id === id ? data : el)) //#1
    this.setState({
        items: this.state.items.map(el => el.id === id ? data : el)
    })
    console.log(this.state.items) //#2
}
```

this is my code. i'm trying to change element inside state array. but `#1` code's result and `#2`'s result are diffrent. I want to change `this.state.item` to `#1` result. is there a any solution?

Comment: State changes are asynchronous, you can't `console.log` on the next line and see the change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because setState is asynchronous in nature, use a callback to log state value which will be invoked after state is update:

```
this.setState({
    items: this.state.items.map(el => el.id === id ? data : el)
  },
  () =>  console.log(this.state.items)
);
```